# Why does Array2D not have a fold operation?

Tags: f#

I just bumped into a case where it would be useful to have fold/foldi methods on an Array2D and I wondered, if there is a reason, why Array2D does not have them.

As my array2d is quite huge, I would not want to transform it first to some other format.

Is it simply a rare use case or are there technical reasons, why those methods were not added? Or is there a way to achieve the same without touching the data in the array (as in move it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think having this function in the standard `Array2D` module would be quite useful. You can open an issue for [the Visual F# repository](https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/) and help us add it :-).

In addition to what @scrwtp wrote, you can also use more direct mutable implementation. For basic functions like this, I think using mutation is fine and it is going to be a bit faster:

```
let foldi (folder: int -> int -> 'S -> 'T -> 'S) (state: 'S) (array: 'T[,]) =
    let mutable state = state
    for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 array - 1 do
        for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 array - 1 do
            state <- folder x y state (array.[x, y])
    state
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any particular reason why `Array2D` doesn't come with those functions in standard, since it does have `map`/`mapi`. Probably the use cases where you want to process a multidimensional array are better served by using a jagged array anyway, so there's little incentive to add them.

There's no reason why you can't define them yourself.

Here's an example of a foldi:

```
let foldi (folder: int -> int -> 'S -> 'T -> 'S) (state: 'S) (array: 'T[,]) =
    seq {
        for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 array - 1 do
            for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 array - 1 do
                yield (x, y, array.[x, y])
    }
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc (x, y, e) -> folder x y acc e) state
```

For a regular fold and a more in-depth explanation how it works, you may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25480710/679898).

Answer (score 0):

I generally use Seq.cast if I need to use folding functions, but this works only for fold (not for foldi).

I am adding this solution, if one needs, for example, scan:

```
let array2dFold folder (state:'State) (source:'T[,]) =
      source
      |>   ( Seq.cast<'T> >> Seq.fold folder state )
```

Since it does not rely on mutation it is highly likely that it is slower than previous solutions.